# Insert current time OR date in PhpStorm Live Template

Tags: phpstorm, live-templates

How can I have a Live Template in PhpStorm that inserts the current time?

For example:

```php
/**
 * @author Person
 * @time   27/07/2021    
 */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just use provided predefined `date()` and `time()` functions with desired format as a parameter:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/edit-template-variables-dialog.html#predefined_functions

**Live template text:**

```
/**
 * @author Person
 * @time   $DATE$ $TIME$    
 */
```

**Edit Variables** (adjust the format as needed in an optional parameter (uses [Java's SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) -- see the function description in the aforementioned link)):

[image]

An example result for the above template:

```
/**
 * @author Person
 * @time   27/07/2021 15:39:01    
 */
```